# Подскажите пожалуйста что не правильно в коде, выдается ошибка:Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{   
 int chislo_slov;//Число слов
 int dlia_vvoda_chisla_slov;
 for(dlia_vvoda_chisla_slov=0;dlia_vvoda_chisla_slov<1;){
     printf("Vvedite chislo slov:");
     scanf("%d\n",&chislo_slov);
         if (chislo_slov<= 10000 and chislo_slov>=2){
             printf("Chislo slov:%d\n",chislo_slov);
             printf("Vvedite slova cherez ENTER:");
             dlia_vvoda_chisla_slov++;} 
         else
             printf("Povtorite popitku\n");}
 char **massiv_vvodimih_slov;
 massiv_vvodimih_slov = (char **)malloc(chislo_slov * sizeof(char));
 char *vvodimoe_slovo;
 vvodimoe_slovo=(char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
 for(int dlia_vvoda_slova=0;dlia_vvoda_slova<chislo_slov;){
     scanf("%s",vvodimoe_slovo);
         if(strlen(vvodimoe_slovo)>=2){
             *massiv_vvodimih_slov[dlia_vvoda_slova]=*vvodimoe_slovo;
             dlia_vvoda_slova++;}
         else
             printf("Vvedite drugoe slovo\n");
 }

 int b=0;
 int a=0;
 int u=0;
 char *massiv_vivoda;
 massiv_vivoda=(char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
 for(int q=1,x=0;q<=u*u-u and x<chislo_slov;){
     for(int u=0,x=0;u<chislo_slov;)
     {
         int slovo1=strlen(massiv_vvodimih_slov[u]);
         int slovo2=strlen(massiv_vvodimih_slov[x]);
         if(massiv_vvodimih_slov[u]==massiv_vvodimih_slov[x])
                break;
         else {
             for(int g=0,p=1,y=slovo1-p,i=slovo2-p;g==0 and y!=0 and i!=0;){
                 if(massiv_vvodimih_slov[y]==massiv_vvodimih_slov[i]){
                     b++;
                     x++;
                     p++;
                     q++;}
                 else{
                     g++;
                     q++;}}
     x=0;
     u++;}
         if(b>a){
             a=b;
             massiv_vivoda[0]=*massiv_vvodimih_slov[u];
             massiv_vivoda[1]=*massiv_vvodimih_slov[x];
         }
         else 
             ;
         b=0;
     }}
 int m=0;
 printf("Dlinna rifmi:%d,\n",a);
 printf("u slov %s i %s",massiv_vivoda[m],massiv_vivoda[m+1]);
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Почему в вопросе отсутствует описание того, что этот код должен делать?

Comment: Что такое `#include <malloc.h>`? В стандартной библиотеке языка С нет такого заголовка. `scanf("%d\n",&chislo_slov);` - что там делает это `\n`? `#include <math.h>` - зачем он здесь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь уже чушь написана

```
char **massiv_vvodimih_slov;
massiv_vvodimih_slov = (char **)malloc(chislo_slov * sizeof(char));
```

Почему вдруг `sizeof(char)`???

Что это такое

```
*massiv_vvodimih_slov[dlia_vvoda_slova]=*vvodimoe_slovo;
```

? Копирование одной буквы? Но даже если исправить предыдущую проблему, у вас в этом момент содержимое массива `massiv_vvodimih_slov` никак не инициализировано, т.е. он содержит мусор, а вы к этому мусору применяете `*`?

Здесь

```
printf("u slov %s i %s",massiv_vivoda[m],massiv_vivoda[m+1]);
```

Но `massiv_vivoda[m]` - это просто `char`, одна-единственная буква. Почему вы пытаетесь ее печатать через `%s`?

Бессмыслицы в коде намного больше, но разбирать нее бессмысленно, ибо не ясно, что этот код должен делать.

Comment: https://server.179.ru/tasks/olymp/016.html#g_t016,вот ссылка на задание